# ImportError: cannot import name 'dedent' from 'matplotlib.cbook'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Hi when trying to import basemap I get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dedent' from 'matplotlib.cbook'
```

I've tried a lot of trouble shooting and can't figure it out.
I am using windows and Anaconda.

In [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2b4p71/trouble_installing_basemap/) reddit it uses the "make" command but that doesn't work for me on windows. From my googling I see its cause thats a linux command.

I've also tried downloading basemap from different locations but it hasn't really helped me.

I've also read that basemap is depreciated and now people use cartopy but I'm also having issues with importing cartopy.

All I am trying to do is overlay data on a United States map and it is giving me so many issues. If someone can please help me I would really appreciate it.

For those curious in case I can do it another way, here is the basemap code I am trying to implement:

```
df_city_salary = df[["Location","average_salary"]]
scale=1

map = ccrs(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=32,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)

# load the shapefile, use the name 'states'
map.readshapefile('st99_d00', name='states', drawbounds=True)

# Get the location of each city and plot it
geolocator = Nominatim()
for (city,count) in df_city_salary:
    loc = geolocator.geocode(city)
    x, y = map(loc.longitude, loc.latitude)
    map.plot(x,y,marker='o',color='Red',markersize=int(math.sqrt(count))*scale)
plt.show()
```

**TL;DR: Easiest way to install basemap. ELI5 installing basemap for an idiot**

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing for those curious:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)

ax.set_extent([-135, -66.5, 20, 55], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()) ## Important
df_range = len(loc)
color = df['average_salary'].div((df_range*100))
plt.scatter(coordinates.latitude,coordinates.longitude,alpha = 0.6, c= color, cmap="bwr_r")
plt.show
```

So I ended up using cartopy and it required some finagling. I ended up using a reddit thread with a good step by step on how to install cartopy. It required me to uninstall and reinstall cartopy in a particular way.

This was the output:
[image]